# Net.TCP needs to be restricted to TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl

For utilizing Net.TCP as a protocol i'm wanting to restrict it to use only TLS 1.2.  However, every time i turn off TLS 1.0 i can't make a connection from my web-application to the server.  What could be causing this and how do i fix this issue?

Comment: According to this [blog post](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2016/04/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/) you need .Net 4.5+ for TLS1.2.

Comment: I currently have .Net 4.5+ installed on the server, am targeting version 4.6 in the application and can use TLS1.2.  However, i can't disable TLS1.0 without the site breaking.

Comment: If the site is accessible from the Internet disable tls1.0 and use https://www.ssllabs.com for testing the effect.